# PureScript - Pass arguments to main using the command line

Tags: javascript, purescript

PureScript programs export a *main* function which is invoked when you run the program. But it's unclear how to pass arguments to it, or if that is possible.

Consider the following simple program, which capitalizes a string.

```
module Main where

import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Prelude (Unit, discard)

import Data.String (toUpper)

message :: String 
message = "Satisfaction Rating: 8.23"

main ∷ Effect Unit
main = do
  log ( toUpper ( message ) )
```

Which outputs

```
SATISFACTION RATING: 8.23
```

This program is executed when `spago run` is invoked.

My question is as follows:
How can the argument `message` in the code example, be passed in via the command line, creating a custom message capitalizer?

The updated run command would look something like:

```
spago run --message="new_message"
```

And the updated output would look like

```
NEW_MESSAGE
```

In short, how do you pass values to a **PureScript program from outside?**

Comment: In Haskell we have [`getArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs), maybe TypeScript has something similar?

Comment: I think tagging your questions with `haskell` is counterproductive. PureScript is different enough from Haskell that it's difficult to answer all but the most basic questions without PureScript-specific knowledge or experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a PureScript program with `spago run`, it runs under Node. Therefore, to get command-line arguments, you need to as Node.

And look: there is a PureScript binding for the relevant Node facilities - [the `argv` function](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-node-process/8.2.0/docs/Node.Process#v:argv) from `purescript-node-process`. It's an effect that returns an array of arguments:

```hs
import Node.Process (argv)

main = do
  args <- argv
  log $ show args
```

A quick examination of `spago run --help` reveals that arguments can be passed to the program via the `-b` parameter:

```
spago run -b somearg
```

For multiple arguments, quote them:

```
spago run -b "somearg anotherarg"
```

---

Note that this works on Linux (and presumably macOS), but fails on Windows, where Spago for some reason ignores the quotes and tries to interpret `anotherarg` as its own argument. This is clearly a bug. [This issue](https://github.com/purescript/spago/issues/804) seems relevant.